# node js sequelize define a field inside model with type of another model

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

i tried to import the model and give the field the type of the model but i get error that its not assignable.

```html
import { User } from './';

followerId: {
    type: User,
    allowNull: false,
}
```

(btw i know you can get the field with relations but i need another field with the same type)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that you need an association:

https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html

```
YourModel.hasOne(User, {
    foreignKey: {
      name: 'followerId'
    }
});
User.belongsTo(YourModel);
```

and use `include` in queries:

```
const result = await YourModel.find({
  where: {
    // ...
  },
  include: User
})
```

Comment: yeah i know, but this is model of follower, i am already getting one field with user association (the user who followed), i need another field with type user (the user who followed by that guy)

Comment: That's not a problem to add multiple associations if you want.

Comment: oh is that ok to add multiple associations bettween 2 tables?